# LWC: how to dynamically get translated value from Label

Tags: lightning-web-components, customlabel, translation

In Aura we used to do this:

```
let labelName = 'mylabel';
$A.getReference("$Label.c."+ labelName);
```

In LWC $A is not accessible anymore.

Following the documentation I can only see a way to get access to Label's value through import.
As far as I know import don't work dynamically. By this I mean that you need to know which label you want the value of in advance. 
In our case the label's name would be stored in a Custom Metadata

I was hoping for a solution involving Apex and/or SOQL but could not find anything.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need dynamic labels? What's the purpose of this?

Comment: I am developing a dynamic form engine. It reads configuration from metadata and renders a multistep wizard.
The point is avoid code deployment when the business wants only to change a few labels or fields. That's the reason why all config is read from metadata.
Everything needs to be translatable.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically get a label via Apex using this slightly hackish technique:

```
Component.Apex.OutputText output = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
output.expressions.value = '{!$Label.' + labelStringPassedIn + '}';
String labelValue = String.valueOf(output.value);
```

Unfortunately you'll need to call this for each label you want to retrieve.

This works in a lightning context.

Comment: This doesn't work in an LWC, please see my comment below!

Comment: Try making your class an actual controller, ie ```global ApexDatabase(Object controller) {
  }
  global ApexDatabase(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
  }```

Comment: Also, it used to work... so don't judge too harsly. I said it was a hack.

Answer (score 1):

In an LWC you can wrap an Aura function with eval() and it will work still.

I have been trying to dynamically retrieve a Custom Label for an LWC as it contains a Decryption Key, but it doesn't seem possible.

Also the comments above using Component.Apex.OutputText won't work, I get back this error:

```
Visualforce Component types can only be created within a controller class for a Visualforce page.
```

Try wrapping your Aura code in eval like this:

```
eval('$A.getReference("$Label.c.' + labelName + '")');
```

Comment: This does seem like a good technique... as long as they continue to allow `$A` in lwc.

Answer (score 0):

You can not import label dynamically. Here are the conversions from twitter where we have talked about the same thing.

It does include a message from Principal Architect at @Salesforce. This is not possible now but it will be there in the future.

And Dynamic import hasn’t made it to a JavaScript standard yet. It is a level 4 proposal
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import/#import

https://twitter.com/TheVishnuKumar/status/1107558419983032320